# Count events within date ranges specified in a second table

Tags: r, data.table

I am working with daily observations of temperature and precipitation, in a table that looks like this:

```
          date      temp     prec
 1: 2020-03-01  9.339748 47.54746
 2: 2020-03-02 23.860849 38.50318
 3: 2020-03-03 12.860331 21.20262
 4: 2020-03-04 26.607505 45.16723
 5: 2020-03-05 28.273551 73.05506
 6: 2020-03-06  2.321138 72.14995
 7: 2020-03-07 16.315059 21.93333
 8: 2020-03-08 26.880152 25.71862
 9: 2020-03-09 16.991615 78.85127
10: 2020-03-10 14.241827 49.59946
```

I also have a table showing the dates where growth stages of corn were attained:

```
   growth_stage date_attained
1:           VE    2020-03-08
2:           V2    2020-03-11
3:           V3    2020-03-21
4:        V5-V6    2020-03-26
5:        V7-V9    2020-04-03
6:           R2    2020-06-14
7:           R4    2020-06-30
8:           R5    2020-08-06
9:           R6    2020-08-23
```

What I need to do is, within each date interval between growth stages, calculate a few functions based on the weather data.
Examples of such functions would be:

- count of days with no rain (prec < 1 mm) # days with no rain
- count of rainy days (prec >= 1 mm) # rainy days
- count of days with temperature > 25 C # temperature greater than 25 C

For example, the date range for the `VE` stage would be from `2020-03-08` to `2020-03-10`, `V2` would go from `2020-03-11` to `2020-03-20` and so on so forth. Those would be the time windows within which I should calculate the weather variables.

The functions to calculate weather counts need to be generic since I have quite a few ones to calculate (besides the three provided as an example above).

The expected table would be something like (showing only first two rows):

```
   growth_stage                date.range count.days.no.rain count.rainy.days count.temp.gt25
1:           VE   2020-03-08 ~ 2020-03-10                  0                3               1
2:           V2   2020-03-11 ~ 2020-03-20                  0                10              3
```

and so on.

I could do this "manually" (i.e. by subsetting the date ranges for each growth stage from the weather table and calculating the weather functions), but it would create a very messy code and I want to make it look more R-style.

Data with a reproducible example:

```
# load required packages
library(data.table)

# generate artificial weather data
dates <- seq(as.Date("2020-03-01"), as.Date("2020-08-31"), by="days")
set.seed(123); temps <- runif(length(dates), min=1, max=30); prec <- runif(length(dates), min=0, max=80)
dat.weather <- data.table(date=dates,
                          temp=temps,
                          prec=prec)

# paste text
dat.growth <- "
growth_stage;date_attained
VE;2020-03-08
V2;2020-03-11
V3;2020-03-21
V5-V6;2020-03-26
V7-V9;2020-04-03
R2;2020-06-14
R4;2020-06-30
R5;2020-08-06
R6;2020-08-23"

# tidy up a bit
dat.growth <- setDT(read.table(textConnection(dat.growth), sep = ";", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

# subset original weather table using as example dates from the VE stage
out <- dat.weather[dates %between% c("2020-03-08", "2020-03-10")]

# simple functions for specific counts of weather events
sum(out$prec < 1)
sum(out$prec >= 1)
sum(out$temp > 25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
dat.growth[, date_attained := as.Date(date_attained)
           ][, date_to := shift(date_attained, type = "lead", fill = max(dat.weather$date)) - 1]
#    growth_stage date_attained    date_to
#          <char>        <Date>     <Date>
# 1:           VE    2020-03-08 2020-03-10
# 2:           V2    2020-03-11 2020-03-20
# 3:           V3    2020-03-21 2020-03-25
# 4:        V5-V6    2020-03-26 2020-04-02
# 5:        V7-V9    2020-04-03 2020-06-13
# 6:           R2    2020-06-14 2020-06-29
# 7:           R4    2020-06-30 2020-08-05
# 8:           R5    2020-08-06 2020-08-22
# 9:           R6    2020-08-23 2020-08-30
dat.weather[dat.growth, on = .(date >= date_attained, date <= date_to)
            ][, .(
              date_range = list(range(date, date.1)),
              count.days.no.rain = sum(prec < 1),
              count.rainy.days = sum(prec >= 1),
              count.temp.gt25 = sum(temp > 25)
            ), by = .(growth_stage)]
#    growth_stage            date_range count.days.no.rain count.rainy.days count.temp.gt25
#          <char>                <list>              <int>            <int>           <int>
# 1:           VE 2020-03-08,2020-03-10                  0                3               1
# 2:           V2 2020-03-11,2020-03-20                  0               10               3
# 3:           V3 2020-03-21,2020-03-25                  0                5               2
# 4:        V5-V6 2020-03-26,2020-04-02                  0                8               2
# 5:        V7-V9 2020-04-03,2020-06-13                  1               71               6
# 6:           R2 2020-06-14,2020-06-29                  1               15               5
# 7:           R4 2020-06-30,2020-08-05                  1               36               5
# 8:           R5 2020-08-06,2020-08-22                  0               17               1
# 9:           R6 2020-08-23,2020-08-30                  0                8               2
```

I'm using a non-equi (range-based) join in the second step, so we need to add a variable I'll name `date_to` for each row, and the last value will be the max of `dat.weather` (over to you if there's a better default if there is much more data than you want/need).

From there, it's a simple range-based join.

I chose to do `list(range(.))` instead of `paste(date, date.1, sep=" - ")` since I wasn't certain if this was a final reporting step or an interim. If the latter, then I always prefer to keep the original class of the objects, so `date_range` is a list-column. (If you look at the resulting `date_range[[1]]`, it's just a vector length-2, `Date`-class.)

Answer (score 2):

Essentially the same as r2evans' solution, but with a rolling join instead of a non-equi join. You might find it slightly cleaner.

```
dat.growth[,date_attained := as.Date(date_attained)][
  dat.weather, on = .(date_attained = date), roll = TRUE, nomatch = 0
][
  , {
    date_rng <- range(date_attained)
    norain <- sum(prec < 1)
    .(
      from_date = date_rng[1],
      to_date = date_rng[2],
      count.days.no.rain = norain,
      count.rainy.days = .N - norain,
      count.temp.gt25 = sum(temp > 25)
    )
  }, growth_stage
]
#>    growth_stage  from_date    to_date count.days.no.rain count.rainy.days count.temp.gt25
#> 1:           VE 2020-03-08 2020-03-10                  0                3               1
#> 2:           V2 2020-03-11 2020-03-20                  0               10               3
#> 3:           V3 2020-03-21 2020-03-25                  0                5               2
#> 4:        V5-V6 2020-03-26 2020-04-02                  0                8               2
#> 5:        V7-V9 2020-04-03 2020-06-13                  1               71               6
#> 6:           R2 2020-06-14 2020-06-29                  1               15               5
#> 7:           R4 2020-06-30 2020-08-05                  1               36               5
#> 8:           R5 2020-08-06 2020-08-22                  0               17               1
#> 9:           R6 2020-08-23 2020-08-31                  0                9               2
```

I don't think a list or text column for the date range is as handy as two separate columns.

Comment: I certainly agree with "two separate columns"!